# Query result data is displaying after page reload

Tags: php, class, oop, object

This is my code.

index.php file:

```
$viewer_id = $_SESSION['viewer_id'];
    $db = new Database('144.76.6.45','5432','3331','asd','31sd23');
    $db->querySelect("SELECT * FROM users WHERE vk_id = $viewer_id");
    $row = $db->STH->fetch();
    if(empty($row)){
        require 'template/default/not_logged.php';
    }
    else {
        require 'template/default/logged.php';
    }
```

This part is understandable. Connecting to database, doing query. If viewer's id is in db - logged.php if not - not_logged.php

Lets say viewers id is already in db.

logged.php file:

```
<div id="text-right">
                            <p>Игровой ник: <?php $user->getEuName(); ?></p>
                            <p>Cоциум: <?php $user->getSociety(); ?></p>
                            <p>Основная профессия: <?php $user->getMainProfession(); ?></p>
                            <p>Дополнительная информация: <?php $user->getNotes(); ?></p>
                            <p>Ищу команду для совместной охоты: <?php $user->getWantTeam(); ?></p>
                        <div class="edit-info"><a href="#">Редактировать</a></div>
                        </div>
```

This methods are getting info from db.

```
class User extends Database {
    public $vk_id;
    public $eu_name;
    public $eu_society;
    public $eu_notes;
    public $eu_want_team;
    public $eu_data;

    function __construct() {
    parent::__construct('144.76.6.45','5432','eu','eu','eu123');
    }

    function getEuName() {
        $this->querySelect("SELECT eu_name FROM users WHERE vk_id = $this->viewer_id");
        $row = $this->STH->fetch();
        print '<b>'.$row['eu_name'].'</b>';
    }

    function getSociety() {
        $this->querySelect("SELECT eu_society FROM users WHERE vk_id = $this->viewer_id");
        $row = $this->STH->fetch();
        print '<b>'.$row['eu_society'].'</b>';
    }

    function getNotes() {
        $this->querySelect("SELECT eu_notes FROM users WHERE vk_id = $this->viewer_id");
        $row = $this->STH->fetch();
        print '<b>'.$row['eu_notes'].'</b>';
    }

    function getWantTeam() {
        $this->querySelect("SELECT eu_want_team FROM users WHERE vk_id = $this->viewer_id");
        $row = $this->STH->fetch();
        if($row['eu_want_team'] == 'TRUE') {
            print '<b>Да</b>';
        }
        else {
            print '<b>Нет</b>';
        }
    }

    function getMainProfession() {
        $this->querySelect("SELECT eu_main_profession FROM users WHERE vk_id = $this->viewer_id");
        $row = $this->STH->fetch();
        print '<b>'.$row['eu_main_profession'].'</b>';
    }

}
$user = new User();
```

And this is user class with get methods.(he is included in index.php like database.php(db connection class) is).

Everything is ok, but when viewer comes to page, the data of methods(query results) doesn't show, they show only **AFTER RELOAD!** I don't know whats the problem. Please solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you posted the credentials to your db in the __construct function? If so, i'd be careful with that

Comment: Nah, i change it randomly when was writing this question. Please solution..

Comment: Where is `$_SESSION['viewer_id'];` defined?

Comment: It is defined in js code, js variable viewer_id is equal to session viewer_id, its under this code, and has nothing to do with this problem

Comment: The problem is in dispaying, the methods are displaying results AFTER RELOAD, i dont know why